# React Router issue. Whenever login button is clicked. I am directed to a blank page with the homepage link appended to the login page link is made

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-component

Whenever I click the login button, I am navigated to a blank page with the homepage link  appended to the login page link. It looks like this:
[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5jsj.png)

Here is my code for the login button.

```
 <Button onClick={() => {navigate("./homePage")}} className='Createuserbutton'  >Login </Button>
```

Here is my index.js code containing the router elements.

```
<Router>
<Routes>
  <Route exact path='/login' element={<Login />} />
  <Route exact path='/ModuleReviewForm' element={<ModuleReviewForm />} />
  <Route exact path='/commentBox' element={<CommentBox />} />
  <Route exact path='/homePage' element={<HomePage />} />
  <Route exact path='/logout' element={<Logout />} />
  <Route exact path='/account' element={<Account />} />
  <Route exact path='/searchPage' element={<SearchPage />} />
  <Route exact path='/searchPage' element={<SearchPage />} />
</Routes>
```

I am wondering if I am referencing the page properly

Comment: As a tip at the bottom of your Routes component have a route <Route path="*" element={<h1>404 Page not found</h1>} /> Instead of getting a blank page you would have gotten this 404 Page not found. header element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `react-router-dom@6`. Routing/navigation in RRDv6 can use either absolute or relative paths. The difference is a leading `"/"` for the path. `navigate("./homePage")` is a relative path from the current location.

The following are the same:

- `navigate("./homePage")`
- `navigate("homePage")`

The result is that the user is navigated to a "homepage" relative to the current path.

Since `"/homePage"` is a root route you should use an absolute path.

```
navigate("/homePage")
```

`navigate("../homePage")` could also work since you are in the `"/login"` route.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass "/homePage" to `navigate` without the `.`